# Laravel 8 - Insert column of sums of child's columns and show it

Tags: php, laravel

I want to sum `money` column from `payments` table:

[image: Payments Table]

Then, append it to every `Client` in `index` method (I'm getting all `user->clients`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent has aggregate methods for relationships to do this already:

```
$clients = Client::where(...)->withSum('payments as sum', 'payment_money')->get();

foreach ($clients as $client) {
    echo $client->sum;
}
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Other Aggregate Functions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) `withSum`

Comment: It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$clients = Client::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->paginate(20);

$clients->each(function ($p) {
    $p->sum = $p->payments()->sum('payment_money');
});

return compact('clients');
```

Comment: This does n+1 queries.

Comment: @IGP Are you want to say, that the first element is not included?

Comment: I'm saying your code produces a query for each time `$p->payments()->sum('payment_money');` is executed.